# What's the meaning of "Tootski"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In this scene from *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Jordan Belfort is sitting across from Mark Hanna, who is rhythmically
hitting his chest with his fist, and snorting cocaine:

> Mark Hanna: **Tootski?**
>
> Jordan: Oh, no. Thank you, though.

What's the meaning of "Tootski" ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tootski):

> Slang for cocaine.
> Code word used by Bill Murray in early SNL scenes. Wearing sunglasses and acting shady, he'd offer "tootski", then quickly glance around for any narcs, hold a straw to the bump, and say "Go!".
> by matatopa January 2, 2010

So, simply put, Mark Hanna is offering the cocaine to Jordan, who gently refuses.

Comment: Drug users often give their habits a childish or humorous-sounding name in order to minimise the negative connotation.

Comment: @Valorum yes, that indeed makes sense, thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's not really from multiple scenes, but a single skit, "Rock against Yeast" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx9VGQDNMJA .  (Or perhaps, this skit started the usage and he's worked it in to others, but I can't find any clips outside this one).

Comment: 'Like 'brewski' for a beer. Jocular -ski ending.

Comment: From "toot" + "-ski".
"Toot" definition from Merriam-Webster: v.t. 2: "to take in (a drug, such as cocaine) by inhalation" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toot)
"-ski" (meaningless, light-hearted suffix, as used in "brewski").

Comment: @Ergwun nice find, I believe it's worthy of its own answer actually.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - it's really, really, common.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey what is common? The slang word? I disagree, unless you mean for people living in the USA?

Comment: @freedomn-m -no, just having read people saying things in books, magazines, online, etc, or seen it on TV shows and in movies, like 'let's meet for a brewski after work' for abut 20 years.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ah, thought you were talking more about the `toot` part :)

Comment: @freedomn-m - once you understand brewski (recreational intoxicational fun involving, in this case, a brewed product) you can instantly or rapidly  'get' bongski, tootski, bluntski, joinstski, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - And of course, ["snortski"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-beKX4wYrI)